# Как лучше подойти к реализации создания подключения к базе MySQL, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

Товарищи, хотелось бы испросить совета в следующем вопросе: 
Положим, у нас имеется `ASP.NET` проект, подгружающий данные из базы (MySQL). Как лучше реализовать это дело: создать **статический** класс, в котором будет статическая переменная подключения (то есть, условно, одно подключение для всех пользователей приложения), или же лучшим решением будет для каждого отдельного пользователя **создавать своё** подключение?

Comment: Ага... при одном подключении один умный юзер запустил длиннючий запрос, а остальные курят - коннекция-то занята...

Comment: для каждого создавать своё подключение

Comment: @Akina ну вот я как раз думал об этом) Просто сейчас я использую именно такую модель, где каждый юзер имеет своё подключение. Вдруг были бы аргументы против этого)

Comment: Если вы используете ado.net, а вы его скорее всего используете, но оно само внутри себя держит пул подключений и вам самому в принципе не надо задаваться подобными вопросами.